# Django equivalent for pattern matching

Tags: python, django, django-models

What is the equivalent for this query in django

```
title like 'Book %'
```

Imagine I have those records in db: Book 1, Book 2, Book 3 and Books.
currently I'm using djangos filter method for a queryset this way

```
queryset.filter(title__startswith='Book') # which is title like 'Book%'
```

and this returns all the above records from the db. I need only Book 1, Book 2 and Book 3 results, how could this be achieved django way?

Comment: Add a space? `title__startswith='Book ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a space to the query, so:

```
#                          space added ↓
queryset.filter(title__startswith='Book ')
```

otherwise you are querying for `LIKE 'Book%'`.